# Astaro Security Gateway Firewall/Proxy won't let me access my local webserver: is PAC file the best solution?

Tags: configuration, proxy, local-area-network

I have this Astaro Security Gateway Version 7 which acts as a firewall and proxy...
I need to access from all the office to a pc on my lan that has apache on it: 192.168.1.100
When I open it Astaro's proxy says:

Astaro Security Gateway Version 7 http://www.astaro.com 
 An error occurred while handling your request

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://192.168.1.100/mysite
Error message: Target service not allowed

I can circumvent the error configuring my browser's proxy exception but I have a lot of clients and no Active Directory so I'd like to plan this with attention.
Changing the Astaro configuration would be the sweetest thing (so if anyone has hints... :) ) but I've also read about a .pec file to configure automatically browser settings and I've managed to prepare it correctly:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
```

{
// variable strings to return
var proxy_yes = "PROXY 128.0.20.254:8080";
var proxy_no = "DIRECT";
if (shExpMatch(url, "http://128.0.0.37*")) { return proxy_no; }
if (shExpMatch(url, "http://128.0.0.210*")) { return proxy_no; }
if (shExpMatch(url, "http://128.0.0.94*")) { return proxy_no; }
// Proxy if PC is on local LAN
// if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.1.0", "255.255.255.0"))
// return "PROXY 192.168.1.1:8080";
else
return "PROXY 128.0.20.254:8080";
}

And put it on a little webserver: works as a champ.

Do anyone has a nice idea to "spread" it fast?
A double click - batch, a regedit file, anything that's not Active Directory related?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No news on the astaro side but here's my solution:

There's a regkey:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
Settings\AutoConfigURL

which I've set with the patch to the webserver where I have the PEC file and exporting it now I can easily install my new rules on any client and control all of them modifying just my PEC file.

Have fun!